# Is Wiener measure a Borel measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm not sure that I understand the Wiener measure in right way. Here's what I think.

Wiener measure is the measure on the classical wiener space C([0,1]) with sup norm. And it satisfies the properties of Wiener process or Brownian motion.(Like $B_t-B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$ )

My question is, what is the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra of Wiener measure on C([0,1])? Is it Borel $\sigma$-field? Or at least containing every open set of C([0,1]) ?

Comment: Yes, it is a probability measure on the Borel sigma algebra, the sigma algebra generated by all open sets.

Comment: You can check this on two books, first "Brownian motion and Stochastic Calculus" by by Karatzas and Shreve and the other is book the one saz always quotes  "Schilling, Partzsch, Böttcher - Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes"   Lemma 4.1 unless mistaken. regards

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to complete the measure, and still call it "Wiener measure".  This is analogous to "Lebesgue measure":  You could define it on the Borel sets of the line, or you could complete the sigma-algebra to the "Lebesgue measurable sets".